# How to have a balanced padding when a line is broken into 2 parts?

Tags: html, css, padding

In the following snippet, I've noticed that adding left/right padding gives a more balanced color highlighting as desired, see 2. for more details:

```css
.a { 
    font-size: 4em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: #ff800f;
}

.b { 
    padding: 0 0.2em;
}

#c { width: 200px; }
```

```html
1. <span class="a">Hi there</span> not enough space at left/right in comparison to the height of the highlighting
<br>
2. <span class="a b">Hi there</span> better
<br>
3. <div id="c">Hello and <span class="a b">Hi there</span></div>
```

**Question: when a color-highlighted line is broken into two parts, like the `Hi / there` here in example 3., how to make that there is automatically more padding at the end of the first line, and start of second line?**

Here in example 3., it should be like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply `box-decoration-break: clone` (requires a vendor prefix such as `-webkit-` for most browsers except for Firefox) to the `span`.

`clone`:

> "Each box fragment is rendered independently with the specified
> border, padding, and margin wrapping each fragment..." -(MDN)

```css
.a {
  font-size: 4em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: #ff800f;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
}

.b {
  padding: 0 0.2em;
}

#c {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
1. <span class="a">Hi there</span> not enough space at left/right in comparison to the height of the highlighting
<br> 2. <span class="a b">Hi there</span> better
<br> 3.
<div id="c">Hello and <span class="a b">Hi there</span></div>
```

Further information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-decoration-break

Comment: Not all browsers are webkit browsers.

Comment: A vendor prefix is required for browsers except for Firefox. See the link. I'll add the Firefox line for you.

Answer (score 0):

No break space is one solution for spacing challenges `&nbsp`.

`3. <div id="c">Hello and <span class="a b">Hi&nbsp &nbspthere</span></div>`

Comment: Thanks! Can you convert your code into a "code snippet" so that we can preview your result easily?